# Dirac function in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{4 \pi |x|}$, $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $h(x)=\nabla^2 g =\delta(x)$ in distribution, i.e.$\int f(x)h(x)dx = f(0) $ for arbitrary $f(x)$ with compactly support.

I don't know how to show the integral of $h(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $1$, so can't get $h(x)=\delta(x)$ in distribution.

Comment: @Winther yes $trD^{2}$ is the Laplacian

Comment: @Winther It's right, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if $x\not = 0$ then $h = \nabla^2 g = \nabla\cdot \left(\frac{x}{4\pi|x|^3}\right) = 0$. This means that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \nabla^2 g d^3x = \int_{B(0,r)} \nabla^2 g d^3x $$

where $B(0,r)$ is any sphere of radius $r>0$ around the origin. Next use the [Divergence theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergenceTheorem.html) to find

$$\int_{B(0,r)} \nabla^2 g d^3x = \int_{B(0,r)} \nabla\cdot\left(\frac{x}{4\pi|x|^3}\right)d^3x = \int_{\partial B(0,r)} \left(\frac{x\cdot \hat{n}}{4\pi|x|^3}\right) dS = \frac{r}{4\pi r^3}\cdot 4\pi r^2 = 1$$

since the integrand is constant over $\partial B(0,r)$.

Comment: I got it. And do I need to show other properties of $h(x)$ to make sure $h(x)$ is a dirac function?

Comment: @user147893 You can use the same type of argument to show that $\int f(x)h(x)dx = f(0)$. This is really the defining relation for the delta function. btw I should warn you that this is a physicist's way of solving this problem. I'm sure there are better (more rigorous) ways of solving this.